# Make Bootstrap Button Transparent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I make my button transparent? I have been trying to use .btn-transparent but cant seem to get it to work. The button just keeps turning grey.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-transparent">SEARCH</button>
```

Comment: Can't you make your own class?

Comment: Which bootstrap version you use? I mean "btn-primary-outline" is the class of bootstrap4(v4-alpha). This class can not work in bootstrap3.

Comment: There is no `btn-transparent` class in any version of Bootstrap.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

make css to `.btn-primary-outline`

example like this : https://jsfiddle.net/472cxwg9/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking to do. Thank you!

Comment: **UPDATE 5/11/2017**: The correct class for this in [BS v4-Alpha](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#outline-buttons) is actually `btn-outline-primary`.

Answer (score 21):

Use

```
class="btn" and style="background-color:transparent"
```

instead of

```
 class="btn btn-primary-outline"
```

result

[image]

Answer (score 18):

You can do this in Bootstrap 4 without any in-line styling

```
<button type="button" class="btn bg-transparent btn-outline-primary"></button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[**Bootstrap 4**](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/) introduced *button link* style: `.btn-link`:

> Deemphasize a button by making it look like a link while maintaining button behavior

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button>
```

The `.btn-link` class has `background-color` set to `background-color: transparent;` (also the button borders are transparent `border-color: transparent;`).

Comment: This won't look like a button anymore. OP asked how to make the background transparent and is adding outline styles.

Answer (score 2):

Just use btn class and you'll get a transparent button. For example:

```
<button class="btn"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap 3 I added:

```
.btn-primary-outline {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

To:

```
<div class="col-xs-3" style="margin-top: 25px;">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-outline">
<span style="display: inline; font-size: 30px; color: #007bff;" class="material-icons save">
</span>&nbsp;
</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Bootstrap 5, you can use any of:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Primary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Secondary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Success</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Danger</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Warning</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info">Info</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">Light</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Dark</button>
```

Docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/buttons/#outline-buttons